# How to resolve invalid character Database exception in liquibase

Tags: oracle, liquibase

I have the following Liquibase query:

```
begin  
for x in (select table_name from dba_tables where owner='${schema}') loop  
  execute immediate 'grant select, delete on ${schema}.' || x.table_name || ' to ${schema}';  
end loop;
end;
/
```

This runs fine in SQL Developer. But when run from Liquibase I get the following error:
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ORA-00911: invalid character
ORA-06512: at line 3
In the XML changeset I have specified endDelimiter="/" As per the error the issue is with line 3 which is the execute statement.
I tried experimenting like removing the semicolon from the end of execute statement. But nothing worked.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Liquibase and it's not clear if the code works in SQL Developer for the same schema value (or if you change the placeholder for a real schema name there; if not it wouldn't find any data in the cursor query...), or why you're granting to the owning schema. But anyway - do any of the tables in that schema have quoted identifiers?

Answer (score 0):

- Liquibase also support yaml format, which is more suitable for embedding complex SQL/PLSQL code.
- '/' in this context is not part of PL/SQL grammar. It instruction for program sqlplus/SQLDeveloper to demarcate end of PL/SQL block to be executed. If you do not use sqlplus and you have only one PL/SQL block you can omit it.
- It does not make sense to grant privileges to yourself. You created those tables, you own them you already have all privileges.

Comment: Using / as the statement delimiter  (and setting endDelimiter="/") is appropriate for executing PL/SQL via Liquibase since Liquibase uses semicolon as default delimiter and otherwise would not know where this PL/SQL block (statement) ends.

Answer (score 0):

Are you providing the value for ${schema} at Liquibase execution time?

Comment: Yes its value is passed in the Java program arguments